# DLL with console tools

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application

Im working on a class library DLL with tools for making console outputs easier. Im not interesting in making it self executing. I will only use it as a helper library for other projects. Does the DLL/project still need to be a console application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No - use a class library type [project](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/library-with-visual-studio)

You may need to take into account if you are on .NET Core or not but I would use a .NET Standard target if possible